# Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility nuget in .Net Core causes EventLog setup error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I've added `Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility` nuget to my ASP.NET Core project to be able to use System.Management.dll API. The problem is now it fails starting up the application when setting up the EventLog:

```
System.PlatformNotSupportedException: EventLog access is not supported on this platform.  
at System.Diagnostics.EventLog..ctor(String logName, String machineName, String source)
at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventLog.WindowsEventLog..ctor(String logName, String machineName, String sourceName)
```

I think the reason is because `Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility` contains `System.Diagnostics.EventLog` and so it tries to use it and it's [not compatible](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/3330) with ASP.Net Core. I think it should use `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventLog`.

Any ideas how I can use `Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility` without getting this EventLog error? Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to use `System.Management`? Which .NET Core version are you using? You don't need `System.Management` if you want to use Powershell Core. Even with the compatibility package you still need to target Windows, not just create a cross-platform binary

Comment: I need to use ```System.Management``` in order to do a WMI query local windows users. If there's another way I'm happy to try. How do I set the target for the compatibility package?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out upgrading the target version of my ASP.NET Core app from Net 5.0 to 6.0 seems to have fixed it.